# number of letters to be deleted from a string so that it is divisible by another string

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am doing this problem https://www.spoj.com/problems/DIVSTR/

We are given two strings S and T.
S is divisible by string T if there is some non-negative integer k, which satisfies the equation S=k*T

What is the minimum number of characters which should be removed from S, so that S is divisible by T?

The main idea was to match T with S using a pointer and count the number of instances of T occurring in S when the count is done, bring the pointer to the start of T and if there's a mismatch, compare T's first letter with S's present letter.

This code is working totally fine with test cases they provided and custom test cases I gave, but it could not get through hidden test cases.

this is the code

```py
def no_of_letters(string1,string2):
#     print(len(string1),len(string2))
    count = 0 
    pointer = 0
    if len(string1)<len(string2):
        return len(string1)
    if (len(string1)==len(string2)) and (string1!=string2):
        return len(string1)
    for j in range(len(string1)):
        if (string1[j]==string2[pointer]) and pointer<(len(string2)-1):
            pointer+=1
        elif (string1[j]==string2[pointer]) and pointer == (len(string2)-1):
            count+=1
            pointer=0
        elif (string1[j]!=string2[pointer]):
            if string1[j]==string2[0]:
                pointer=1
            else:
                pointer = 0
    return len(string1)-len(string2)*count
```

One place where I think there should be confusion is when same letters can be parts of two counts, but it should not be a problem, because our answer doesn't need to take overlapping into account.

for example, S = 'akaka' T= 'aka' will give the output 2, irrespective of considering first 'aka',ka as count or second ak,'aka'.

Comment: Have you considered that S could be 'akbaabka' with T = 'aka'? The b's would need to be removed to make S divisible by 'aka'. Hidden cases may be like that.

Comment: Since you've chosen to code with generic variable names, redundant expressions, and no comments, it's difficult to extract the algorithm you think you're implementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the solution is much more straightforward that you make it.  You're simply trying to find how many times the characters of `T` appear, in order, in `S`.  Everything *else* is the characters you remove.  For instance, given RobertBaron's example of `S="akbaabka"` and `T="aka"`, you would write your routine to locate the characters `a`, `k`, `a`, *in that order*, from the start of `S`:

```
akbaabka
ak a^
# with some pointer, ptr, now at position 4, marked with a caret above
```

With that done, you can now recur on the remainder of the string:

```
find_chars(S[ptr:], T)
```

With each call, you look for `T` in `S`; if you find it, count 1 repetition and recur on the remainder of `S`; if not, return 0 (base case).  As you crawl back up your recursion stack, accumulate all the `1` counts, and there is your value of `k`.

The quantity of chars to remove is `len(s) - k*len(T)`.

Can you take it from there?